# Keyboard troubles

Tags: keyboard

I recently got a great new keyboard, the Perixx PX-1100, but I'm having trouble with it. If you look up and study said keyboard, you will see that it has backlighting. There is a knob to adjust the brightness, and a button that changes the light color or turns it off. When you plug it in or the computer starts with the keyboard already plugged in, The light is blue. The color order is "Blue>Red>Purple>Off". I've found out that pressing this button operates different things. Depending on which color the keyboard is already on, pressing this button does the equivalent of "Button 1", "Button 2", "Button 3", or "Button 4".

- If the backlight is blue and you press the button (changing to red), it performs "Button 3".
- If it's on red and you press the button (changing to purple), it performs "Button 2".
- If the the backlight is purple and you press the button (turning off the light), it performs "Button 4".
- If the backlight is off and you press the button (changing to blue), it performs "Button 1".

It also seems the hold down the button as long as it's on the color. This causes issues where if I'm in a browser, I can't click on certain things. I understand that usually, "Button 1" is left click, "Button 2" is right click, and "Button 3" is clicking your scroll wheel. I want to disable the light change button's ability to be the equivalent of Button 1, 2, 3, or 4. I plugged it into a Windows laptop and had no such problem.

Using the command `xev` tells me that:

- Changing the color to blue is "Button 8".
- Changing the color to red is "Button 2".
- Changing the color to purple is "Button 3.
- Turning off the backlight is "Button 8".

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution that worked for me, not for Ubuntu (i'm using Fedora) but I suppose work for all linux X Window system.

The logic is to remap the bad key trapped by X11.

1) Step
Create in your `$HOME` directory a file named `Perixx_Ignore_Keys` and insert the following lines:

```
0xFF020001   unknown
0xFF020002   unknown
0xFF020003   unknown
0xFF020004   unknown
```

2) Step
Execute (put them in your startup file with a script or other) the following command:

```
sudo /usr/lib/udev/keymap /dev/input/by-id/usb-Chicony_USB_keyboard-event-if01 $HOME/Perixx_Ignore_Keys
```

enjoy

BaBBa

Comment: Have mercy on my lack of understanding and actual ability, but I'm getting a message saying "sudo: /usr/lib/udev/keymap: command not found". I could make all kinds of guesses as to what the problem is, but I'll shut up and ask, what now?.

Comment: You can find a remap method for ubuntu in http://askubuntu.com/questions/362373/how-to-remap-key-codes-without-usr-lib-keymap-which-is-gone-in-saucy-and-in